# How would I aggregate login and log out date time stamps as total logged in time replacing NULL with the time right now -- in T-SQL?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query for sql server that returns this "table" below. The query uses some joins to link the data together. What I'm trying to do is add up each interviewers logged in time and in addition turning NULL into the time at this moment.

```
INTERVIEWER NUM_COMPLETES   projectId   loginDateTime   logoutDateTime
002                2    43407      2011-09-20 22:59:15.193  NULL
004                1    43407      2011-09-20 23:06:32.287  NULL
007                1    43407      2011-09-20 23:02:30.930  NULL
007                1    43407   2011-09-20 00:37:01.213 2011-09-20 01:15:00.197
010                3    43407      2011-09-20 23:04:46.547  NULL
013                1    43407   2011-09-20 00:36:16.923 2011-09-20 01:14:59.440
029                3    43407   2011-09-20 22:58:55.083 2011-09-20 23:30:56.987
029                3    43407   2011-09-20 23:31:05.243 2011-09-21 00:02:27.560
029                3    43407     2011-09-21 00:02:55.527   NULL
032                1    43407     2011-09-20 22:59:19.590   NULL
036                1    43407     2011-09-20 23:02:33.497   NULL
041                1    43407     2011-09-20 22:59:55.020   NULL
```

Should turn into

```
INTERVIEWER NUM_COMPLETES   projectId   TotalTime
002                2      43407            8
004                1      43407            10
007                1      43407            4
008                1      43407            7
```

It's like a date diff that is summed up per interviewer.

Here is a sample + sanitized tsql statement that I am using

```
SELECT tbl1.INTERVIEWER, tbl1.NUM_COMPLETES, tbl2.projectId, tbl2.loginDateTime, tbl2.logoutDateTime
FROM 
(
SELECT k_Id, FirstName AS INTERVIEWER, COUNT(result) AS NUM_COMPLETES
FROM db1_table, db2_table
WHERE k_Id=Interviewer
GROUP BY k_Id, FirstName, result
) AS tbl1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT projectId, loginDateTime, logoutDateTime, userId
FROM session_tbl
WHERE loginDateTime >= '2011-09-20 0:0:0.0' AND projectId = '43407'
) AS tbl2
ON tbl1.k_Id=tbl2.userId
ORDER BY INTERVIEWER
```

Thank you for any help -- I've been struggling with this the past couple of days!

Comment: Have you tried converting to UNIX Timestamps and deriving the total in numeric values?

Comment: That sounds like it would work but I haven't really dealt with UNIX Timestamps in MSSQL.

Comment: A possible complete solution that takes in account login/logouts that intersect. http://explainextended.com/2009/06/11/flattening-timespans-sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a standard `GROUP BY` to do this.

```
select
    userId, 
    projectId, 
    sum(datediff(hour, loginDateTime, isnull(logoutDateTime, getdate()))) as totalHours

from session_tbl

group by userId, projectId
```

Comment: That worked! I get some results back that are negative and I'm not sure how to handle that.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify that comment a little more, I get back some rows in TotalTime as negative numbers -- not sure why because it's addition!

Comment: @RMacy: Run the following query and see if you get any results: `select * from session_tbl where loginDateTime > logoutDateTime or (loginDateTime > getdate() and logoutDateTime is null)`. If so, you have bad data.

Comment: I believe the issue that I reported to have been because my time is in UTC. I changed getdate() to getutcdate(). Thanks for the help man!

Comment: @RMacy Ah, yes; the delights of time zones. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is going to help you or not but it's what is going through my head.

I would personally go with having php just enter those values (INTERVIEWER NUM_COMPLETES   projectId   TotalTime) when the user logs out. Have a table that keeps track of sessions (time of log in, last impression and a log out time {if user just closed the browser and default to last impression} and then that simplifies the SQL.

It can also be a security measure checking that everything matches periodically.

Personally there is only so long I will fight with something before I start thinking of different ways to achieve the same result.